# Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() shows 50% free memory but I still face OUT OF MEMORY error for JAR application

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory

I am running stand alone Java (JAR) application with VLCJ, SWT, DJNativeSwing and many other libraries. I added log for memory using Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(). This shows 50% free memory exists but still I face OUT OF MEMORY ERROR on machine. On windows 7, I set Virtual Memory, increase-decrease Heap Size but still I am facing the same issue.

I am facing this issue when app runs for more than 3 days approx. So to test the change, I need to wait for 3-5 days. Is there any way to make sure that OUT OF MEMORY gets resolved or what is the exact memory used ?

Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()

Comment: You have a memory leak my friend. Turn on heap dump in error, and perhaps run your application with flight recorder. Then you’re going to have to learn the wonders of analysing a heap dump.

Comment: Use a profiler, like yourkit or Jprofiler and figure out if its causing any memory leak. Later on you can fix it. These tools might give you intuitive hints about lemory leak as well.

Comment: What is the exact exception message? Because an `OutOfMemoryError` is also thrown if you try to create too many threads. In that case the exception message is "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread"

Comment: Thanks to all of you.. I am looking for things as you suggested. Hope I can resolve it.